# What is an ORM in a web application?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, orm

I recently got a reply from a server company asking if we are using an ORM in our application  which does all the work of sifting application side (like Rails) or if we write reams of SQL, embedded functions etc which would make the database server do the processing for you.

Can anyone explain what is meant by this. Our web application is made up of PHP scripts with functions that make calls to the database to retrieve rows of data, then PHP processes these rows as needed to return results to the user.

thanks

Comment: I agree about using google for this. Use this link: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=orm&aq=f&aql=&aqi=g10&oq=

Comment: Thanks to all who left helpful answers, I find it so much more rewarding to engage with real people than google, best wishes.

Comment: Do you people realize that this particular stackoverflow question is one of the first results when you google ORM? This is how the search results on google are created. If questions were only allowed to be asked once on the internet, you would only have one answer on the internet, which would suck because you would only have one particular phrasing and point of view. Mostly it would just be official documentations which often leaves a lot to be desired pedagogically. Sry for rant, it's just so annoying when you google something and the answer you find is "google it you moron".

Comment: @WalturBuerk I agree with you, people on SO need to loosen up a little, I have seen so many good questions and answers downvoted or removed because they didn't technically fulfil SO's "guidelines".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It basically makes your database tables appear like objects on the PHP side of your site so you can easily manipulate data.

For example if you have a User table, getting this user's name is as easy as doing: `$myUser->getName();`

adding a new user in your database would be:

```
$myUser = new User();
$myUser->setName('John Doe');
$myUser->save();
```

Of course this is pseudo code (actually PHP Symfony/Doctrine code), but it's a simple example so you get the point.

Answer (score 3):

It is an Object Relational Mapping. See link to wikipedia below.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

Comment: Updated to reflect Bears' comment above from mapper to mapping.

Answer (score 3):

An ORM is an abstraction that is supposed to simplify working with a relational database in an object oriented language.  It's basically a set of classes and methods that let you create, retrieve and update data without using SQL directly.

For instance instead of writing 
    $result=mysql_query('select * from sandwiches where color='green' and size='2');

you can use an interface like
    $result=$sandwiches->get('color'=>'green',=>'size'=>'2');

and the ORM turns this into SQL and executes the query, taking care of joins, etc.

Popular PHP ORMs are [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/)

If you don't know whether you're using one, than it's pretty unlikely that you are!

Comment: So how do you identify which ORM is being used in a PHP web application?

Comment: @BhargavSushant it should be apparent in the includes... if you mean one for which you have the code. If you mean someone else's running web application, there should be no way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

ORM is Object Relational Mapper. which maps the java objects to the database tables and lets you perform some database transactions thorough your code. 
EX of ORM tools are like Hibernate, Ibatis ..

Answer (score 0):

ORM is used for Mapping your database objects to your application objects.

In a simple application using ORM, you should have functions that gets/sets data from/to DB should return appropriate application object/objects.

Answer (score 0):

ORM is a [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) article on Object Relational mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Object Relational Mapping is an easy way of mapping Database objects ( tables, views ... ) to classes/objects in OOPL. 
Hibernate and NHibernate are a few examples of ORM. it does all the tedious task of handling and mapping result sets..